# moving around virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, algorithms

[image]
I'm  creating  virtual keyboard using javascript/html/css. And I  can't  find a good algorithm for  moving from one button  to another in  different directions (top-bottom, left-right). Lets say  I have focus set to any of the buttons - how should I  find which  button  should  be focused next.  any  thoughs and  ideas would  be  appreciated.

Here is  code structure  sample

row with functional  keys

```
<div class="keyboard-row">
        <a href="#" id="langSwitch" class="largeKey" lang-code="en" data-index="0">ENG</a>
        <div class="charRow">
             <a href="#" class="key" id="key2" data-index="1">1</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key3" data-index="2">2</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key4" data-index="3">3</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key5" data-index="4">4</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key6" data-index="5">5</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key7" data-index="6">6</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key8" data-index="7">7</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key9" data-index="8">8</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key10" data-index="9">9</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key11" data-index="10">0</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key12" data-index="11">_</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="enter" class="largeKey" data-index="12">Search</a>
    </div>
```

row only  with  chars

```
<div class="keyboard-row">
        <div class="charRow">
             <a href="#" class="key" id="key1" data-index="0">a</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key2" data-index="1">s</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key3" data-index="2">d</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key4" data-index="3">f</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key5" data-index="4">g</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key6" data-index="5">h</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key7" data-index="6">j</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key8" data-index="7">k</a>

             <a href="#" class="key" id="key9" data-index="8">l</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also layout is formed dynamically based on language file config. So rows that have  letter characters can have different  number of  keys  depending  on language  selected.

Functianal keys are  static  for all languages.  Language setting  is saved in a javascript object

```
var langObj = {
......
  row3: [
        {
            value:"q"
        },{

            value:"w"
        },{

            value:"e"
        },....
],
row 4 :[...].....
}
```

where each row  property responds to keyboard row layout

I've added "data-index" attribute  to each key in a row as suggested by   Kilian Foth so now with jquery I  can move horizontally. code is next(might need some  improvements)

```
   function moveLeft(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $el = $(e.target),
                $parentRow = $el.parents(".keyboard-row");

            if(!$el.is($("a:first", $parentRow ))){
                var nextIndex = parseInt($el.attr("data-index")) - 1
                $parentRow.find("[data-index='" + nextIndex + "']").focus();
            }
            else $parentRow.find("a:last").focus();
        }
```

Now the main problem is moving verticaly. I  would suggest finding coordinates of currently focused  button and  then figuring out which  button vertically intersects by Y-coordinates with the current one and if it even exists. But dont  know how to do it yet

Comment: What kind of data structure do you have the key definitions in? It looks as if you'll need both an "index in row" (to move left and right) *and* a screen X coordinate (to decide which of the keys in the previous row is physically closest when moving up and down).

Comment: I have edited my  question and provided sample  data structure. This is  just what I  find convenient.  but any  amendments can be done further

Comment: Why do you need this focus change direction anyway? I.e. what is 'focused next', why would *you* want to change focus in any particular direction?

Comment: well, I need to "walk" around my "virtual keyboard"with keyboard left-rigth , up-down  arrows. I've found  horizontal move solution(added to my post). Now need to move vertically.  A good  solution seems "to decide which of the keys in the previous row is physically closest when moving up and down"(suggested by Killian Foth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it would result is much more code, there's nothing inherently wrong with adding "nextLeft, nextDown, etc." to your keys. You'll be able to 100% ensure which key is next when navigating, so all of the guess work is gone.

If you insist on a solution that uses solving, give each key an x offset and width, then when down is pressed, move to the key whose center is closest. You may not even have to define that information if it's already being laid out visually in the DOM, there's already properties for that.

Comment: well, I  have 8 languages to  support so each  time the layout would be  slightly  different due  to different number of letters in alphabets. That's why to implement first idea would be very laborious for me. second is  actually what I have already . I'll share implemented solution a bit later.